# debuginfo-install using a local file

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

im trying to debug a program I wrote but the gdb tells me an error :

Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-istall glibc-2.9-2.i686

when im trying to use that command, it gaves me an error because my fedora is disconnected from the internet.

however, I have glibc-2.9-2.i686 in my fedora's cd.

how can I use debuginfo-install with my local file ?

or there is another solution ?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can call **debuginfo-install** with the **--enablerepo** option, so you can use your fedora cd as the repository for installation.

Answer (score 1):

First, unless you want to debug glibc itself, you don't actually *need* the debug info packages for glibc, and installing them is unlikely to help you.

Second, glibc-2.9-2.i686 which you have on the Fedora CD is *already* installed: no Linux system can function without it.

Lastly, you can download appropriate debuginfo package from [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/10412561/com/glibc-debuginfo-2.9-2.i686.rpm.html), burn the RPM to a CD and bringing it over to your Fedora box. It's also possible that you already have the glibc-debuginfo RPM in i386/debug/ on your existing CDs.